# invalid module names, ignored: multi_company_account

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

my path multi_company_account/branches/9.0 **openerp**.py(and openerp with double underscores)

i'm getting a strange warning and can't figure out where is a problem:

**Error:**

> openerp.modules.loading: invalid module names, ignored:
>   multi_company_account

```
{
    'name': 'Multi company for accounting module',
    'version': '1.0',
    'category': 'Account',
    'sequence': 10,
    'summary': 'Multi company for accounting module',
    'description': """""",
    'author': 'Tiny',
    'depends': ['base',
                'account_budget',
                'account_cash',
                'account',
                ],
    'data': [
        'views/product_view.xml',
        'views/sale_view.xml',
    ],
    'demo': [],
    'test': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,
}
```

Comment: make sure u ve written correct spelling of module  name inside file somewhere

Comment: i have only 1 file it's openerp

Comment: then i believe u r missing the name "__ init __.py" as well make sure u shd also have that file